# LDAP over startTLS

Tags: ldap, starttls

I'm going to start TLS connection for LDAP. I have followed this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-tls) which uses gnuTLS tool for generating self-signed certificates.

Slapd starts well.

When i run the command:

```
    ldapsearch -x -b "dc=platalytics,dc=com" -H 'ldaps://122.129.79.69' -ZZ
```

it shows my whole DIT structure.

But wen i run this command:

```
    ldapsearch -x -b "dc=platalytics,dc=com" -H 'ldaps://122.129.79.69' -ZZ
```

it gives error:

> ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

I'm new to LDAP. I don't have much understanding. Can anyone please explain what could be the issue?

Also i came to know conventional SSL certificates does not work well with LDAP. We have to create separate certificates for LDAP to startTLS connection. Is it the case?

Comment: what is the difference between two commands? They looks same to me.

Answer (score 3):

looks like your commands are the same?

For StartTLS Use

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=platalytics,dc=com" -H 'ldap://122.129.79.69' -ZZ
```

(ie not LDAPS) when using StartTLS.
-jim